# Gremlin, join vertices of same type and add edge when the properties empNo and mgrno matches

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin, vertex

I have vertices with properties like 
`vertex("empNo","age","Date","mgrNo")`
`a(101,20,'dd-mm-yy',0)`
`b(102,22,'dd-mm-yy',101)`
Since mgrNo of b matches with empNo of a ie, a is the manager of b.
 I have to add an edge between a and b.
Please tell me how to do this in gremlin .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to iterate all vertices.  You could do it with a `sideEffect` pretty easily:

```
g.V.has("mgrNo",neq,0).sideEffect{
  g.V.has("empNo",it.mgrNo).next().addEdge("manages",it)
}
```

Note that if you are using a graph that supports transactions you will need to `commit()` your changes to persist them.

Comment: Hi Stephen, it is only adding one edge. Suppose I have data like  empNo,Name,age,mgrNo
101,Alice,32,0
102,Bob,30,101
103,Mary,28,101
104,Lisa,25,102 .  I want to iterate through each and every vertex and add relationship if mgrNo of that vertex is not zero

Comment: The code still looks right to me.  It iterates all vertices looking for employees who have managers (i.e. mgrNo != 0) and for each one it adds a "manages" edge between that employee and the manager.  If you've tried the above and it fails, please provide some sample data in the form of a groovy script I can paste into the Gremlin Console and I can test it out myself.

Comment: Its working properly now . Thank you so much for the reponse.

Comment: The code works fine with small number of vertices but if i have vertices like 16k vertices and when I'm running the above code , its adding only one edge and stopping.Why is it happening like this.I'm using BatchGraph to load the data.

Comment: `BatchGraph` is for a very specific type of data loading use case and such loading happens at the Blueprints level.  I think you might anticipate problems if you try to run Gremlin over it (which is what the above code is doing) as all the Blueprints methods/features required by Gremlin are not implemented in `BatchGraph`.

Comment: I'm only loading the data using BatchGraph ( Im crearing only vertices). Now to add edges between the vertices whose mgrNo and empNo matches I'm using the above code. Now it will be available in the form of normal data right.So it has to work.

Comment: yes - i guess that should work.  you don't mention an error/stacktrace, so my first thought would be to check what happens when you do `g.V.has("mgrNo",neq,0).count()` - if that returns 1, then that's why you have one edge.  i assume that would indicate problems with your data load.  If it returns more, then I would expect an error somewhere and a stacktrace when you executed, because there is no null checking in the `sideEffect` step and therefore `.next` would throw a `NoSuchElementException` if `g.V.has("empNo",it.mgrNo)` returned nothing.

Comment: The queries `g.V.has("mgrNo",neq,0).count()` and `g.V.has("empNo",it.mgrNo)` are both independenly working correctly.When i use `g.V.has("mgrNo",T.neq,0).sideEffect{g.V.has("empNo",it.mgrNo).count()}` to check it is also working correctly.But when i use .next() then it is only establishing one relationship and stopping and it is not throwing any exception

Comment: if you are saying that `g.V.has("empNo",it.mgrNo).count()` returns a number that is greater than 1 then, yes, you would only get one edge, but I would expect one edge per vertex returned from `g.V.has("mgrNo",neq,0)`.  is that your situation?

Comment: Actually it has to be like that . But it gave only edge even though it had 911 vertices  for `g.V.has("mgrNo",neq,0)`.I think i have found the reason behind it. If mgrNo has a number which is not equal to any of the empNo. Then it is breaking in the middle and even it is not giving any error

Comment: How can i implement the above gremlin code using GremlinPipeLine in java ?